# MVC 4 Project IIS executionTimeout not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

IN my server IIS any Request take more than 3 min need to kill 
Its lead a problem of server hanging due to high CPU Usage and RAM Memory

```
<system.web>
    <globalization culture="en-US" uiCulture="en-IN" />
 <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5" />
     <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" executionTimeout="180" />
</system.web>
```

also included in

HttpContext.Server.ScriptTimeout = 60 * 3;

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially [ask], and [edit] your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, if you want to set the connection for a request, I suggest you could try to set the IIS site's advanced setting connection timeout.

More details, you could refer to below steps:

Open IIS Manager, click on the site and go to Manage Web Site -> Advanced Settings.

Under Connection Limits option, you could modify the timeout value.

[image]

Comment: Its only 120 Seconds but my request exceed that time and running , i need to kill if its exceed

Comment: As far as I know,the techicial reason timeout don't work with async handlers. If you add IHttpAsyncHandler handler in your application the timeout will not be triggered. Could you please tell me is there any custom handler you have used for your MVC application?